# What is addNotify();?

Tags: java, methods, overriding

I've tried to find a laymans definition of `addNotify()` but I can't really get any answer using Google.

As far as I know, when overriding `addNotify()` in my class, I should call `super.addNotify();`
and then do whatever else afterward.

My question is, does `addNotify()` run automatically? What is it's purpose and what happens when I override it and furthermore, why would I ever want to override this method?

Thank's.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My question is, does addNotify() run automatically?

Yes.  The precise where and when depends on the internals of the AWT implementation.

> What is it's purpose

It is as described in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addNotify%28%29).  It is very low level stuff that is part of the "glue" that connects the AWT world to the native windowing world.  (I'm being deliberately high-level and vague.  If you want the nitty-gritty details, download and read the OpenJDK source code.)

> and what happens when I override it

You'd probably break AWT :-)

> and furthermore, why would I ever want to override this method?

I can't think of a good reason to do this ... unless you were trying to port AWT to a different operating system or a different native windowing system.

Comment: Thank you for answering. 

I'm reading this book and it overrides addNotify() but all he has it do is super.addNotify() and then calls another method that he created which basically starts up everything. He really isn't changing much . is that okay in that example?

Comment: @ElmedinZelenkic - without seeing the code, it is hard to say.  Does the code work?

Comment: `addNotify(){
super.addNotify();
startGame();
}`


Basically what  `startGame();`does is it creates a new Thread that has its run Method overriden. 

Basically it just activates the new Threads run method by calling `newThreadName.start();`

So to cut it short, the second method, the one called `startGame();` contains code that creates a new thread and starts it.
I hope that makes sense. If not, thank you for your answeres, they really helped a lot.

Comment: @ElmedinZelenkic - It sounds to me like what "the author" implemented is a hack.  He is using addNotify purely because it gets called at a convenient time.  Not recommended ... though, presumably it works.

Comment: @StephenC This is how the author justifies the use 
`Wait for the JPanel to be added to the
JFrame/JApplet before starting`
Is it justified usage?

Comment: @Sohaib - I don't think so.  He could do that with a container listener.

Answer (score 1):

[**Component#addNotify()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addNotify%28%29) is a method in `java.awt.Component` class. The purpose of this method as stated in the API:

> Makes this Component displayable by connecting it to a native screen
>   resource. This method is called internally by the toolkit and should
>   not be called directly by programs.

Answer (score 1):

Methods `addNotify()  / removeNotify()`  are the only hooks the AWT provides in which we can correctly destroy and recreate the OpenGL context, given that the underlying native widget is being destroyed.
`addNotify()` is used by low level components to interact with the underlying peer on the operating system so that something REALLY happens, not just pretty pictures on a screen. 
**Better to avoid using this method.**