# How to set the title for a frame from a externalized JPanel in another class?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have 2 classes: `MainClass.java` and `BasicDataPage.java`, while the first class is a `JFrame` with a `CardLayout` and the second class is a `JPanel` with only a label.

When I click on the button in the `MainClass` the card shows the contents of the `JPanel BasicDataPage` (in this example there is only 1 card, in my real program there are several more).

But I am not able the change the title of the window / frame from inside the `JPanel`:

`MainClass.setTitle("BasicDataPage");` wont work, since I can not make a static reference to the non-static method `setTitle()`.

My first impuls would be to change the title, when the button is clicked, BUT in my real application I have another class called `Navigation.java`, which contains the listeners to the navigation-buttons. So it's the same problem how to change the title:

`Buttonclick in MainClass -> Navigation gets active -> needs to talk to MainClass and change the title`

OR

`Buttonclick in MainClass -> BasicDataPage gets active -> needs to talk to MainClass and change the title`.

So how do I change the title of the `JFrame` from a `JPanel` in another class?

**MainClass.java:**

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class MainClass extends JFrame{
    public CardLayout contentCardsLayout = new CardLayout();

    BasicDataPage basicDataPage = new BasicDataPage();

    JButton changePageButton = new JButton("Goto BasicDataPage");

    public MainClass(){
        super("My MainClass");
        setBounds(300, 50, 400, 400);
        setLayout(contentCardsLayout);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        changePageButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                contentCardsLayout.show(getContentPane(), "basicDataPage");
            }
        });

        basicDataPage.setName("basicDataPage");

        add(changePageButton);
        add(basicDataPage, "basicDataPage");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");

                    MainClass window = new MainClass();
                    window.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**BasicDataPage.java:**

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BasicDataPage extends JPanel {

    public BasicDataPage() {
        add(new JLabel("MainClass - BasicDataPage"));
    // This does not work, since I can not make a static reference to the non-static method setTitle()
    // MainClass.setTitle("BasicDataPage");
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a static method in MainClass and call that.

Comment: @hamena314 Is the JPanel being added to the JFrame where you wanted to set the title?

Comment: Let's avoid `static`, as it leads down a dark, dangerous and windy path and instead consider something like `SwingUtilities.windowForComponent`

Comment: @MuratK. I can not use the non-static method `setTitle()` in a static method.

Comment: @user3437460: Yes it is in the constructor of `MainClass` via `add(basicDataPage)`.

Comment: @hamena314 You mean the JPanel is indeed added into the JFrame ?

Comment: @user3437460: Now I am not so sure about this anymore. I am trying to use the hint that MadProgrammer gave me. But I keep getting a `NPE`, as no frame is found. I thought, that `add(basicDataPage, "basicDataPage")` adds it to the frame called `window`. This however seems to be wrong?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: When I try to get the `windowForComponent` in the constructor of `BasicDataPage`, I get a `NPE`: `JFrame f1 = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(this);`. It seems like the `JPanel` does not really get added to the `JFrame`, altough I use `add(basicDataPage, "basicDataPage"`?

Comment: @hamena314 Then override the addNotify method if the panel

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Thanks for the hint, I got it to work. But reading more into `addNotify()`, I found several sources that said, [overriding it is bad](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15520331/1368690) or even [calling it is bad :D](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386477/how-does-addnotify-and-requestfocus-work-in-java-with-jpanel#comment34044910_22386994). But I could not find out WHY calling / overriding it is bad?

Comment: You should never call it yourself and should make sure you call super.addnotify. It's a critical method which sets up the core event listener chain for the component. Another approach might be to have the component have a getTitle method, which the caller uses to change the title, meaning your component never tried to change the title itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your JPanel is added into the JFrame, that is if your `BasicDataPage` is added into your `MainClass`.

Under this relationship, you can easily get the parent container from the added component using `getParent()`:

**Example:**

```
class BasicDataPage extends JPanel{
    //constructors and initializations not shown..

    public void setPrentComponent(){
        Object o = getParent();
        MainClass mc;
        if(o != null && o instanceof MainClass)
            mc = (MainClass)o;

        mc.setTitle(lbl.getText());            
    }   
}
```

If you want to get the top level container. For example, A JFrame added a MainPanel, and MainPanel added another panel..and so on.

If you want to get the reference for the ***top level container*** (i.e. the frame), you can use:

```
SwingUtilities.windowForComponent();
```

---

> how you would call the setParentComponent()?

Assuming you have a class for JFrame and a class for JPanel. I would usually refrain from making any of those class as the main project class. You can have another separate class for driving the codes instead.

```
class TestRunner{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MainClass mc = new MainClass();   //I will rename this class if I were you
        BasicDataPage bdp = new BasicDataPage();
        mc.add(bdp);                      //add panel to frame;
        bdp.setParentComponent();         //Set parent container
    }
}
```

This is from what you have, usually I will not create a customized JFrame but instead, run the Frame in EDT and add the panel which contains all components into the Frame.

Comment: @hamena314 If your panel is added to the frame, you can use this solution. If The 2 classes do not know each other, take a look at the other solution.

Comment: If I put this method into my `BasicDataPage` and call it in the constructor with `setPrentComponent()`, I get a `NPE`.

Comment: @hamena314 You shouldn't do it in the constructor. It gives you NPE because the moment you created the panel, it was not added to any containers yet !!   Put it is a method and call the method only when you need it.

Comment: But the panel does not have any methods. It only shows a label, so the only way to call the method `setPrentComponent()` is via the constructor, or is it not? I am a bit confused now, sorry.

Comment: @hamena314 If it does not have any methods, you can always add one. My example also created a method for that.

Comment: Indeed, but if I create another method i.e. `setTheTitle()` which then uses your method `setPrentComponent()`, I have to call `setTheTitle()` via the constructor. Which is the same as calling `setPrentComponent()` directly from the constructor, or is it not?

Comment: `I have to call setTheTitle() via the constructor` **No..!** Constructor should only contain codes which you use it for initialization (for your case). How could you invoke all things in the constructor? To call `setParentCompoent()`, you can always invoke it via the object. E.g. `new BasicDataPage().setParentComponent()`. You can do this anywere. In the main(), in another class, in another method. Remember, class is only a blueprint. We don't code our program logic in the blueprint.

Comment: But if I write `BasicDataPage basicDataPage = new BasicDataPage().setParentComponent()` in the `MainClass` above the constructor, I get the error `Type mismatch: Cannot convert from void to BasicDataPage`.

Comment: @hamena314 You will need to add it first and you need to invoke the method from a valid place such as within a method. You cannot write it outside the method. I think you need to understand the basics of classes and objects first. Understand getters and setters as well. I have explained way more than what was originally asked.

Comment: You did explain a lot which I am very grateful for. However I still can't get your answer to work, which is why I am asking so much. If I write `BasicDataPage basicDataPage = new BasicDataPage().setParentComponent()` within a method ie. `setTitle()`, there are other parts of the program that now cant "see" `basicDataPage` anymore, like the line `basicDataPage.setName("basicDataPage");` in the constructor of `MainClass`. Before putting `basicDataPage` into the method `setTitle()`, `basicDataPage` was visible globaly, which is not anymore if I put it into `setTitle()`. Thats whats confusing me.

Comment: @hamena314 Hmm, that is up to your program design already. How would you want your program to be driven. Create a main class to drive your codes, and plan how would you let the classes relate to each other. The is also the reason why schools teach class diagrams.

Comment: Could you show in your answer, how you would call the `setParentComponent()`? Maybe I am just misunderstanding you, english is not my first language.

Comment: @hamena314 See my update solution in this post. You should learn some of the basics first. SO is supposed to answer specific programming problem, not to replace schools. =/

Comment: I hope I am not out of line if I ask you, if you could refrain from creating another class for the instantiation of the `BasicDataPage`? Because this is the confusing part to me. You are now instantiating it in another class, which will make the line `basicDataPage.setName("basicDataPage");` in the `MainClass` not work anymore. This line is important for using the `CardLayout` and I dont understand what I am supposed to do to fix it. I've studied C.S. and learned basic concepts of java, but some seem clearer to me than this. So could you use only my 2 classes: `MainClass` / `BasicDataPage`?

Comment: @hamena314 Even if you use 2 classes or only 1 class. You must have a `main()`  for the entry point of the program right? So you can still do the same thing as I did in your `main()`. There is no reason `CardLayout` will not work just because you are running the program from another class. I think from the start you are not having a good design for your classes which gives you endless trouble trying to make the objects see one another.

Comment: @hamena314 Actually I've already answered your question. If you still do not understand how to let the classes communicate, you can start a new question and maybe ask for a demo code from one of the people here to see how to set the frame name according to a label (which is supposed to be a very basic thing. And I would wondered why would you want to set the frame name according to a label though).

Comment: Uhm, the label was your idea? I did not use a label anywhere. :D ... After thinking a bit, I realized, that my `MainClass` is doing the same as your `TestRunner`-class, except for having the instantiations not in the main-method. If I put them there AND the `CardLayout`, my class should work. So the design of the relations of the classes is okay. I'm just not smart enough to put everything into the correct position, will try to figure this out...

Comment: As for you and your answer: I am really thankful for your patience and explanations. Altough I still dont understand your answer fully, it's giving me some directions in where to go from here. So I will release you from my nagging inquiries, accept your answer and wish you farewell.

Answer (score 0):

If both classes do not know the existence of each other, you can have a controller class which keeps a reference to the instance of both classes. From there, get the "title" from the panel and pass it to the frame:

```
class Contorller(){
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MainClass mainClass = new MainClass():
        BasicDataPage bdp = new BasicDataPage();

        mainClass.setTitle(bdp.getTitle()); //Need a setter in BasicDataPage class
    }
}

class BasicDataPage{
    private JLabel lblTitle;

    //constructors and initializations not shown

    public String getTitle(){
        return lblTitle.text();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I create another class `Controller` and put the instantiation of `BasicDataPage` into it, how can I put the object `basicDataPage` into the main class, in order to put it into the `CardLayout`?

Comment: @hamena314 You just instantiate `BasicDataPage` as you would instantiate `MainClass`. Alternatively, you can pass in the reference of the 2 classes to Controller by adding 2 arguments to constructor of Controller like `public Controller(BasicDataPage bdp, MainClass mc);`

Comment: But when I instantiate the `BasicDataPage` in the `Controller-class`, the line `basicDataPage.setName("basicDataPage");` in my `MainClass` constructor would not work, since the constructor does not know `basicDataPage`?